# WPF: Setting Keyboard Focus of DropDownButton

Tags: wpftoolkit

I'm using the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DropDownButton.
Objective, set keyboard focus programatically.

Just setting ddl.Focus() seems to focus the entire control.
I'm trying to get the focus level for keyboard input (so pressing enter pops up the content, also this level of focus is indicated by the presence of the focus rectangle). I have to press tab after setting focus() to get to that 'secondary' level of focus I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can [navigate focus programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.100).aspx). Try this

```
ddl.Focus();
var focusElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement; 
if (focusElement != null)
{
    FocusNavigationDirection direction = FocusNavigationDirection.Next;
    focusElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction)
    {
        Wrapped = true
    });
}
```